# Android layout with maximized width and checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout

How to make layout like image below - maximized to parent but only to width that wrapped element will fit on the right. I end up with layout like in xml below, but when TextView is longer it overlaps checkbox.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i made this using `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your TextView, add the following rule:

`android:toLeftOf="@+id/checkbox"`